# Compile error when trying to use jooq any operator in kotlin

Tags: arrays, postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, jooq

I have problems using jooq with kotlin and the any clause.

Given the following:

- I have a Database field in a postgreSQL database which is an array
- I have search parameters which are a List of Strings
- I want to use jooq any operator to search in the array

I have the following code which is not working:

```
fun findAll(
        someArrayListOfStrings: List<String>?
    ): List<SomeDTO> {
    val filters = ArrayList<Condition>()
    filters.add(TABLE.SOME_FIELD.eq(DSL.any(someArrayListOfStrings)))
}
```

Here I want to dynamically create filters (jooq Conditions) to be added to some SQL statement. It should work to look if SOME_FIELD (PostgreSQL Array Type) contains one of the following strings using the ANY clause (PostgreSQL jooq binding). However I get the following compile-time error:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
>
> > public abstract fun eq(p0: Array<(out) String!>!): Condition defined in org.jooq.TableField

> > public abstract fun eq(p0: Field<Array<(out) String!>!>!): Condition defined in org.jooq.TableField

> > public abstract fun eq(p0: QuantifiedSelect<out Record1<Array<(out) String!>!>!>!):  Condition defined in org.jooq.TableField

> > public abstract fun eq(p0: Select<out Record1<Array<(out) String!>!>!>!): Condition defined in org.jooq.TableField

But my function call should match the third type where QuantifiedSelect is used.

I looked for hours on the internet but was not able to find any solution. Any site I found told me to try the solution I already have. Does anyone have an idea what I could try and why it does not work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're calling here is [`DSL.any(T...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#any(T...)), which takes a generic varargs array (in Java). You're passing a `List<String>`, so this binds `T = List<String>`, which doesn't satisfy the type constraint on the `eq()` method.

But even if you changed that to an `Array<String>`, it wouldn't work because the jOOQ `ANY` operator doesn't do the exact same thing as the PostgreSQL `any(array)` operator. So, just resort to either [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/):

```kotlin
condition("{0} = any({1})", TABLE.SOME_FIELD, 
    DSL.value(someArrayListOfStrings.toTypedArray()))
```

Or just use the `IN` predicate

```kotlin
TABLE.SOME_FIELD.in(someArrayListOfStrings)
```

Comment: For the plain SQL template the right syntax should be: `condition("{0} = any({1})", TABLE.SOME_FIELD, someArrayListOfStrings.toTypedArray())`

Comment: @MatteoCodogno: I can see how the previous version could be confusing, though it's possible to mix template placeholders and bind values. I've changed it to be a bit less confusing. Note that it's better to wrap the `Array<String>` in a `Field<Array<String>>`, then, if you prefer the template placeholder syntax.